# mysql 5.7 & rails 4.2 fail to load on Ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4

Just upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04.1 & MySQL-5.7

Databases were reloaded. Database access OK from mysql console.

Rebooted.

Now,

**rails console** produces the following error:

```
LoadError: libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: 
No such file or directory - 
/var/www/.../shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/mysql2-0.4.5/mysql2/mysql2.so
/var/www/.../shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `require'
```

mysql2.s0 exists in its nominated path

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 linkee admin 447949 Oct 31 17:36 mysql2.so*
```

My understanding is the .so.18 pertains to mysql 5.6, and if so, don't understand why it's still involved.

libmysqlclient.so.18 is not installed.

```
dpkg -l | grep mysql

ii  libdbd-mysql-perl       4.033-1ubuntu0.1       
ii  libmysqlclient-dev      5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
ii  libmysqlclient20:amd64  5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
ii  mysql-client            5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
ii  mysql-client-5.7        5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
ii  mysql-client-core-5.7   5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
ii  mysql-common            5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
ii  mysql-server            5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
ii  mysql-server-5.7        5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
ii  mysql-server-core-5.7   5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
ii  python-mysqldb          1.3.7-1build2
```

Gemfile.lock entry for mysql2: mysql2 (0.4.5)

gem install mysql2 installs OK.

```
gem install mysql2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.4.5
1 gem installed
```

Would appreciate assistance in resolving this issue.

Comment: Rebuild the gem? I.e. remove it and reinstall so that it forces rebuild. Otherwise just install `libmysqlclient18`, multiple client libs can co-exist just fine.

Comment: Unfortunately here is no installation candidate for libmysqlclient18 on xenial.

Comment: But what I do have is: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.20. Got to be some sort of clue.

Comment: libmysqlclient.so.20, is out of libmysqlclient-dev. mysql2 gem has been removed and reinstalled several times to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverted to an earlier version: mysql2-0.4.1.
Now works fine.
Why. I don't know. Maybe there is an issue with mysql2-0.4.5.